# Python audio frequencies

Tags: python, audio, frequency

I have to detect frequencies from a audio. I found some codes but there is a problem:

```
# Read in a WAV and find the freq's
import pyaudio
import wave
import numpy as np

chunk = 2048

# open up a wave
wf = wave.open('Audio.wav', 'rb')
swidth = wf.getsampwidth()
RATE = wf.getframerate()
# use a Blackman window
window = np.blackman(chunk)
# open stream
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format =
                p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels = wf.getnchannels(),
                rate = RATE,
                output = True)

# read some data
data = wf.readframes(chunk)
# play stream and find the frequency of each chunk
print(len(data))
print(chunk*swidth)
while len(data) == chunk*swidth:
    # write data out to the audio stream
    stream.write(data)
    # unpack the data and times by the hamming window
    indata = np.array(wave.struct.unpack("%dh"%(len(data)/swidth),\
                                         data))*window
    # Take the fft and square each value
    fftData=abs(np.fft.rfft(indata))**2
    # find the maximum
    which = fftData[1:].argmax() + 1
    # use quadratic interpolation around the max
    if which != len(fftData)-1:
        y0,y1,y2 = np.log(fftData[which-1:which+2:])
        x1 = (y2 - y0) * .5 / (2 * y1 - y2 - y0)
        # find the frequency and output it
        thefreq = (which+x1)*RATE/chunk
        print ("The freq is %f Hz." % (thefreq))
    else:
        thefreq = which*RATE/chunk
        print ("The freq is %f Hz." % (thefreq))
    # read some more data
    data = wf.readframes(chunk)
if data:
    stream.write(data)
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

It is not my code ı just found it. problem is while loop: in some audios len(data) == chunk*swidth condition not true. However, in some audios its true. How can i find solution and fix or there are any working codes?

Comment: What is the minimal size in your wav files?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KVEQQUqBvwgDPf2JC_uQ0L6M_gzGDG6l
These are working wav files but ı have to find frequencie of more complex audio like song